# display seconds on a jlabel using Thread

Tags: multithreading, timer, count, jlabel

I want to display seconds on a jlabel using a Thread while i move this with directions key. I put one thread, but this runs very slow... take a much delay time to show the seconds.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  This site works best if you include some code in your question, explain what you expected the code to do, and explain what it did instead (include any relevant output or error messages.)  Then maybe somebody can help you to clear up your misunderstanding.

Comment: i want to display passed seconds on a Jlabel using a Thread while i move the jlabel on a panel using left and right keys.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking somebody to write the code for you.  I couldn't do that even if I wanted to do, because I don't remember enough about how Swing _layout managers_ work to be able to tell you how to move a widget at run-time.  In general, most people here won't just write code for you, but they'd be glad to help if you've got some code that you do not understand.

Comment: this my code http://pasted.co/ac1a9f56